# how to fix integer out of range error :$3 error in YACC

Tags: yacc

I am developing a calculator using YACC and I receive this error :
Integer out of rang $3;
I have just now started learning yacc and can't rectify the error I can see the question already but no one has answered

```
%token NUMBER
%%
expr :expr '+'{$$ = $1 + $3;}
%%
#include<stdio.h>
#include "lex.yy.c"
yylex()
{
int c;
c=getchar();
if(isdigit(c))
{
yylval=c-'0';
return NUMBER;
}
return c;
}
int main()
{
yyparse();
return 1;
}
int yyerror(){
return 1;}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$3` refers to the 3rd term on the right side of the rule.  In

```
expr :expr '+'{$$ = $1 + $3;}
```

there are only 2 terms on the right side of the production...

Comment: isn't the plus operator also a term?

Comment: Yes, it is term $2

Comment: @krishnasp `$1` is the `expr` to the left of the `'+'`, `$2` is the `'+'` and `$3` does not exist because there is nothing after the `'+'` in your production.